# JavaScript reorder dynamic index values in input elements after deleting created item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating div blocks dynamically with input elements to which I am assigning incremental ids. Row contains button with possibility to delete created row.

What I need help is: ex. after creating 4 rows with its elements and ids from 1 to 4 when I delete row the ids and names should reorder with new ids from 1 to 3.

my code is like this.

```
let countField = 1;
$("#addUSers").click(function () {
    var user_row = ('<div class="row rm-row">');


    user_row += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">';
    user_row += '<h1></h1>';
    user_row += '</div>';

    user_row += '<div id="workin_user' + countField + '" class="col-lg-9 d-flex gap-1">';

    user_row += '<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 mt-lg-4 mt-md-5">';
    user_row += '<fieldset>';
    user_row += '<label for="worker_' + countField + '" class="label-text">Name Surname<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>';
    user_row += '<input class="form-control label-text" asp-for="worker[' + countField + '].NameSurname" name="worker[' + countField + '].NameSurname" type="text" />';
    user_row += '</fieldset>';
    user_row += '</div>';

    user_row += '<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 mt-lg-4 mt-md-5">';
    user_row += '<fieldset>';
    user_row += '<label for="JobDescription_' + countField + '"class="label-text">Job Description<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>';
    user_row += '<input runat="server" class=" form-control label-text" asp-for="worker[' + countField + '].JobDescription" name="worker[' + countField + '].JobDescription" type="text" />';
    user_row += '</fieldset>';
    user_row += '</div>';

    user_row += '<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 mt-lg-4 mt-md-5">';
    user_row += '<fieldset>';
    user_row += '<label for="deleteWorkRow" class="label-text">DELETE </label>';
    user_row += '<button type="button" id="deleteWorkRow" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>';
    user_row += '</fieldset>';
    user_row += '</div>';

    user_row += '</div>';

    user_row += '</div>';

    $('#inputFieldsContainer').append(user_row);
    countField++;
    /*user_row += ''*/

    $(document).on('click', '#deleteWorkRow', function () {
        $(this).closest('.rm-row').remove();
        countField--;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was attr asp-for, so I replaced with id, and tried with this code and it worked

```
    $(document).on('click', '#deleteWorkRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('.rm-row').remove();
    countField--;

    // Rebuild the rows with updated id and name attributes
    $('.rm-row').each(function (index) {
        var row = $(this);
        row.find('[id^="worker["]').attr('id', function (i, id) {
            return id.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, '[' + index + ']');
        });
        row.find('[name^="worker["]').attr('name', function (i, name) {
            return name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, '[' + index + ']');
        });
    });
});
```